# core data objects removed When Resuming App From Background

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

When retrieving an object which has relationships from core data returns the value as below :

```
<Item: 0x608000ac6190> (entity: Item; id: 0xd00000009704000c <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Item/p9665> ; data: {
    attrNotes = "";
    attributeList =     (
        "0xd000000855a0000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136552>",
        "0xd000000855c4000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136561>",
        "0xd00000085444000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136465>",
        "0xd0000008554c000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136531>",
        "0xd000000854f4000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136509>",
        "0xd0000008552c000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136523>",
        "0xd00000085578000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136542>",
        "0xd00000085540000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136528>",
        "0xd00000085624000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136585>",
        "0xd0000008551c000a <x-coredata://4453E4EF-92A7-4BB3-8062-2515ACA2DC76/Attribute/p136519>",
        "(...and 1 more...)"
    );
    itemAvailabilityTemp = 1;
    itemId = 655;
})
```

But after resuming App From Background the value of "attributeList" is becoming empty.

Can you help me in resolving this?

Comment: `save()` the context, at least in `applicationWillTerminate` and `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Comment: I tried saving the context, even then I'm able to see the issue

Comment: Make sure you save the right context(s). Also, check that `attributeList`s `transient` option is un-checkt.

Comment: I had a code earlier which deletes all the events in 'applicationWillEnterForeground' . I removed that code, which results in resolving my issue. @shallowThought Thanks for your help.